# Magento 2 - Add product edit link on custom grid

Tags: magento2, grid

I have custom admin grid, I want to add product edit link on it.

I have a column that is showing product id, I want to use edit link instead of id. code for that column is this:

```
$this->addColumn(
    'product_id',
    [
        'header' => __('Edit Product'),
        'index' => 'product_id',
    ]
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this action column in your `grid` file. It will add the product edit option in grid.

```
$this->addColumn('action', array(
                        'header' => __('Action'),
                        'width' => '100',
                        'type' => 'action',
                        'getter' => 'getProductId',
                        'actions' => array(
                            array(
                                'caption' => __('View'),
                                'url' => array('base' => 'catalog/product/edit'),
                                'target'=>'_blank',
                                'field' => 'product_id'
                            )
                        ),
                        'filter' => false,
                        'sortable' => false,
                        'index' => 'id',
                        'is_system' => true,
                    ));
```

**I hope this will help**

Comment: Thanks Muhammad Hasham, very helpful